# Douglas-Peucker line simplification algorithm time complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, check-my-answer

I am analyzing the time complexity of the [Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) line simplification algorithm. Reading online I've found that it has a worst-case running time of $O(n^2)$ where $n$ is the number of points on the line. However, I haven't been able to provide complete proof. Here is the pseudo-code I am working with:

[image: pseudo-code]

Here is my analysis:

**Line 1:** $O(1)$

**Line 2:** We can say that it goes through all points in the polyline formed by the first point and the last point in $PL$ and return the point with the maximum distance to the straight line between the mentioned points. We can safely say this is $O(n)$

**Lines 4-6:** If we are here we are doing two recursive calls. **The number of elements used in each call could be different (not always in half). Depends on the point found in Line 2**. Leaving implementation details aside, we can say that splitting is $O(1)$. Also, we have a $JOIN$ operation which would take $O(n)$ to join both lists.

**Line 8:** This is also a $JOIN$ operation but this only takes $O(1)$.

After looking at these steps I think we have the following recurrence relation:

$T(n) = T(index + 1) + T(n - index) + 2n$ where $index \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$

Am I right? If so, how could I prove this is $O(n^2)$? Master Theorem?

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT: Changed description on Lines 4-6. Thus, also changed recurrence formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis seems correct, except for that you need $T(n)=T(index)+T(n-index+1)+2n$ instead because when $index$ is either $0$ or $n-1$ you won't get in the right hand side another factor of $T(n)$, which is not allowed.

In fact, it will yield something very close to the recurrence of the running time in the [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm.

### Worst case scenario

When `index` is either $0$ or $n-1$, the recurrence will boil down to $T(n)=T(1)+T(n-1)+2n = T(n-1) + (2n + T(1))$. You can easily show by induction that $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$ in this case.

### Best case scenario

We assume the input in the recursion will always be cut down by half. That is, the recursion is $T(n)=2T(n/2)+2n$.

Define $b=a=2$ and $f(n)=2n$. Then, $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$.

We can calculate $c_{crit}=\log_{b}(a)=\log_2(2)=1$ and thus $f(n)=2n=\Theta(n)=\Theta(n^{c_{crit}})$.

Now we can directly use the second case to get that $T(n)=\Theta(n^{c_{crit}}\log(n))=\Theta(n\log(n))=O(n^2)$

### Average case scenario

If we assume that the input is a random variable, such that the choice of $index$ is uniformly distributed in $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, then the algorithm takes expected time $\Theta(n\log(n))$. Take a look [at the proof for quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis) to see how its done.

Comment: Thanks for answering, does this means that $O(n^2)$ is a loose upper bound for this, right? And the tighter one would be $O(n\lg n)$?

Comment: @nir_shahar. I changed the information on the question because I was assuming the information was cut in half and it is not. It depends on the farthest point. How would that change the proof?

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX I updated my answer according to it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am only interested in the worst-case scenario, but your explanation of the other cases help me understand better the algortihm.